# Why is my textbook saying the space complexity is O(1)?

Tags: space-complexity

Why does my textbook say that the space complexity for this algorithm is O(1)? I feel like it is O(n) for the size of the Linked List that it is holding.

```
 public static LinkedListNode nthToLast(LinkedListNode head, int k) {
    LinkedListNode p1 = head;
    LinkedListNode p2 = head;

    /* Move p1 k nodes into the list.*/
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        if (p1 == null) return null; // Out of bounds
        p1 = p1.next;
    }

    /* Move them at the same pace. When p1 hits the end, 
     * p2 will be at the right element. */
    while (p1 != null) {
        p1 = p1.next;
        p2 = p2.next;
    }
    return p2;
}
```

Comment: look for things the function is allocating, not things that it is given

Answer (score 3):

When you think of space complexity of an algorithm, you should consider the additional space that the algorithm explicitly allocates. In the example above, the algorithm to find the nth to last `LinkedListNode` in the list simply creates two additional `LinkedListNode` pointers `p1` and `p2` as well as one counter `i` for for loop iteration. The amount of additional memory the algorithm allocates has nothing to do with the length of the linked list passed in. You would still use two `LinkedListNode` pointers and one integer counter regardless of whether the linked list passed to `nthToLast()` was 10 nodes long or 10 million nodes long. Therefore, this algorithm's space complexity is O(1).

Comment: so do we not consider the space allocated based on what is contained in those variables? I understand that the number of variables stored do not change based on the input but if the linkedlist is size 5 or 500 wouldn't the variables store different sizes of space?

Comment: Each variable is a pointer to a `LinkedListNode`. Given the head pointer to the linked list, one can indeed traverse the whole list but that has to be distinguished from what `p1` and `p2` are actually storing -- they are storing pointers (AKA starting memory addresses) of the two `LinkedListNode`s. They are not actually storing the whole linked list.

Comment: so if those linkedlists were arrays would the space complexity be O(n) then?

Comment: No, it would still be O(1). You would still need to keep track of p1 and p2, but now that can be done with simple integers instead of `LinkedListNode` pointers since the data structure of interest is an array. Unless you explicitly allocate a whole other array, make a copy of the linked list, or something of this sort in the algorithm, it will be O(1) in terms of space complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The space complexity is how much memory the algorithm uses as a function of the size of the input. In other words: if the size of the input changed, how much more memory would the algorithm use?

Whether or not the linked list input has `1` node, `10` nodes, or `1000000` nodes, the algorithm uses the same amount of memory. It uses a constant amount because it only allocates `3` variables  (a constant number) -- `int i`, `LinkedListNode p1`, and `LinkedListNode p2`.

UPDATE: It's important to note that `p1` and `p2` just reference a single node. They are initialized to the reference the value of `head`, which would just be the first node in the list. Those two variables don't contain the whole list itself.

```
   head
    |
    v
 [node1] --> [node 2] --> [node 3] --> ..... --> [node n]
  ^   ^
  |   |
 p1   p2
```

Notice in the drawing above, that if we had 1 node or 20 nodes, you'd still only have a single `p1` and `p2`. They may reference different nodes at different times in the algorithm, but only ever contain a single node each.

Comment: Wouldn't there be more space allocated for 10000 nodes though versus 1 node? I don't understand how the same amount of memory will be used for 1 node, 10 nodes, etc... Are you saying that the number of variables stored don't change based on the size of the input therefore the space complexity is 1. What if the size of those variables change based off the size of the input?

Comment: `p1` and `p2` are just the size of a single node. For instance, you set them to `head` which is just the first node in the list. Not the entire list itself.

For example: https://pastebin.com/yFgictJE

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma They are not even a size of a single node, they are just references (pointers).

Comment: if the linkedlists were arrays instead would the space complexity O(n) then?

Comment: @Hamilton - No. Nothing would really change if you kept the algorithm the same. The inputs that get passed to this method are already allocated and that's not really what Big O notation tries to capture. The Big O complexity is about the algorithm itself (the lines of code that make up the method). So space and time complexity try to determine how the code in your algorithm (within your method) behave when various inputs are passed into it. (Although if it were an array you wouldn't need to iterate anything, since you could just index it at `array[array.length - 1 - k]`)

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma Thank you both for your explanations and patience

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm does O(n) iterations, but it does does not allocate any memory for the elements in the list, it only uses the already existing items. The only memory used is for local variables p1 and p2, used to designate the items.

Comment: Doesn't the space of p1 and p2 change based off of the input though?

Comment: Yes, the space is used, but no new space is allocated, only the space which was already created by someone else who created the list before is traversed.